# Value error while adding column with more number of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a column with more number of values in it compared to other columns and it is resulting in value error. how to avoid the error/

```
import pandas as pd
table5={'Roll':[1,2,3,4,5],'Name':['Nidhi','Anil','Poonam','Karambir','Sangeeta'],
        'Marks':[87,45,67,39,78]}
indexelements=['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5']
df=pd.DataFrame(table5,index=indexelements)


df.insert(1,'gender',['F','M','F','M','F','F'])
```

It shows:ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (5)

Comment: Surprise! Surprise! You can't add a series of length 6 to a dataframe of length 5. What exactly do you expect the outcome to look like. You can extend the dataframe length by one row first then add the series but I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Can you be more explicit in what you would like the dataframe to look like after adding the extra column

Comment: I would like to add another row simultaneously filled with NaN values

Answer (score 0):

The number of values in the new column must match the number of rows in the DataFrame, else pandas raises a ValueError.

Here, you are trying to insert `6` values `['F','M','F','M','F','F']`  in the `gender` column, whereas the number of rows in the DataFrame is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


table5 = {'Roll': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Name': ['Nidhi', 'Anil', 'Poonam', 'Karambir', 'Sangeeta'],
          'Marks': [87, 45, 67, 39, 78]}
index_elements=['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5']
df=pd.DataFrame(table5, index=index_elements)
df.loc['S6'] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
print(df)

df['gender'] = ['F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F']
print(df)
```